# iOS: preferredContentSize only work on width, but not work on height

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to use preferredContentSize to change view controller's size in pop over controller. But it only works on view controller's width, doesn't work on view controller's height.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    self.preferredContentSize=CGSizeMake(859, 484);
}
```

Comment: Are there constraints that make the height need to be larger so it ignores the preferred size?